# Trying to copy string variable to clipboard gives me [object Object]

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm trying to set up a button that copies text to the user's clipboard, but when I try to copy a string from a variable, the copied text is [object Object].

```
function CopyButton({ copyText = "sample text" }) {
    
    return (
        <button onClick={ () => { navigator.clipboard.writeText({copyText})}}>{Copy}</button>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not just copying a string variable, you're copying an *object* which has a string variable as a *property*:

```
writeText({copyText})
```

And the default string representation for an object is `"[object Object]"`.  To copy just the string, just copy the string value:

```
writeText(copyText)
```